# A question about the exponential function endomorphism

Tags: proof-verification, conditional-probability, morphism

I have the following problem :

Is the  function $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{k \times x },$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ the only endomorphism/ function $f$ such that

$$f :    \begin{cases} (\mathbb{R}_+,+) \mapsto (\mathbb{R}_+^*,\times) \\\forall (t,u) \in \mathbb{R}_+, f(t+u)=f(t) \times f(u) & \\ f(0)=1 \text{ and $f$ is continuous at point 0}\end{cases}$$

$(\mathbb{R}_+,+)$ denoting the positives reals with addition and $(\mathbb{R}_+^*,\times )$ the strictly positive reals with multiplication ?

Here is how it all began :

We had a probability course about atomic disintegration/ decay, and we had to find which law this probability  abides by, base on the following fact :

> $T$ denotes the time it takes for a radioactive atom to disintegrate. the
>   probability that a radioactive atom has NOT decayed  by time $0\leq t \leq T$ is
>   defined by
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(T>t)=F(t)$$ We assume that $F(0)=1 \text{, $f$ is continuous at point 0 and } \lim_{t \to +\infty} F(t)=0$.
>
> This means we suppose the atom has not disintegrated at $t=0$, but will finally do at some point
>
> It has been proven that $$\forall t_2>t,F(t+t_2)=F(t)\times F(t_2) $$
>
> Let's now define $F_2(t)=\mathbb{P}(T\leq t)=1-F(t)$
>
> Prove that :  $$F_2(t)=1-\mathrm{e}^{\lambda \times t}, \forall
> \in \mathbb{R}, \text{s.t.}\lambda <0 $$
>
> e being the exponential function.

**My attempt**

We need to prove that $F(t)=\mathrm{e}^{\lambda \times t}, \forall \lambda <0$.
If my claim is correct then we just need to check our $\lambda$ :

$F$ must tend to 0 as $t$ tends to $+\infty$ so that $\lambda \leq 0$
$$F(0)=1 \neq \lim_{t \to +\infty} F(t)=0$$

So $F$ is not constant and $\lambda < 0$

And the result follows.

I am aware that there is a proof through analysis, but I wanted to know if this algebraic shortcut would work

Thanks for the help,

T.D

Comment: The notation $e^{k\times x}$ is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @uniquesolution What do you mean

Comment: $(\mathbb R_+, +)$ is a not a group. So I am not sure what you mean by "endomorphism." What kind of structure are you considering $(\mathbb R_+, +)$ to be?

Comment: @Math1000 I used the word endomorphism on monoids sorry

Comment: If your question is about isomorphism a of the groups $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_+^*,x)$ yes the only ones satisfying your continuity assumption plus the value at zero constraint are the exponential $x\to e^{kx}$. But the proof necessarily involves a limit step exploiting continuity. You seem to be assuming the exponential form and just checking that your coefficient has to be negative to have decay. But this does not prove the hard fact.

Comment: @GReyes Can you be a bit more precise and post it as an answer, I think I used the contunuity have I not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. First prove $f(at)=f(t)^a$ for all positive integers $a$.
2. Then extend it to all positive rational numbers $a$.
3. Finally, for an irrational $a$, consider a rational sequence $\Bbb Q\ni a_n >a$ with $\lim_na_n=a$. 
   Then apply continuity to $b_n:=(a_n-a) \,\to 0$.